# What is the best and cleaner way to iterate over Future[Seq[Something]]?

Tags: scala

I'm a new Scala programmer, and i would like to iterate and call another method passing the Something by parameter, but i really don't know how to do it.

```
val b = Future[Seq[Something]] = Future.sequence(b)
b.flatmap ?
```

Comment: b.get.flatmap ?

Comment: It would help a great deal if you could flesh out your example. What is the signature of the thing you want to call, does it expect a `Something`? does it produce new values which you need later? etc.

Comment: Also the first line makes no sense. You have 2 equals signs (presumably the first one should be `:`) and you're using `b` in the right hand side of the definition of `b`. Probably not relevant to the question, but not sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (things <- b) yield things.map(callWhateverAcceptsSomething)
```